# Google Reports Audit Calendar stopped working

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api, google-admin-settings-api, google-admin-audit-api

For some reason the report screen is stopped from five days ago. Any idea?

[image: Google Admin Home]
[image: Admin Home Reports]
[image: Admin Reports Calendar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely the expected delay of Reports that can been seen in the Admin console. Generally, the Reports section is 3-5 days old (the same delay would be seen with the Reports API).

This current delay is also being discussed on Google for Work Connect [here](https://connect.googleforwork.com/thread/10031).

If you see this extending longer than a week behind, I'd recommend reaching out to GfW Support.